# URL Schemes to personal apps

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Is there a way to use URL schemes to open another app (not a common one like maps), without having access to the source code of that app? I'm working for a company that has several apps, and they've tasked me to build another app that will concatenate all of their other apps. If I really need to, I can email my boss and ask about setting up the codes.

If it helps, I'm using XCode 7.3.1, in Swift 2.

By the way, I checked for similar questions, but couldn't find any. If you do find one, send a comment with the link and I'll delete this question if the answers the the other question help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question isn't clear. As long as you know the URL scheme of the other app, assuming the app has one, you can launch it.

Comment: Exactly, I just don't know the URL Scheme. That was the problem.

Comment: You should have stated that in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was implied when I said I didn't have access to the source code. Fortunately, @Brandon knew what I meant.

Comment: @Do you have a way to do this that works currently?

Comment: @JFed-9 I also would like to be able to do more than just open the app. How do I query the app without having the source code or the documentation? I'm willing to try anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Download the application onto your device (sync to iTunes to get the IPA) or to iTunes. Right click and choose show in explorer or finder.

Now you have the IPA. Change the extension to .zip and unzip it. Open the payload folder.

Go into the application's folder (Right-Click Show Package Contents on OSX).

Open "Info.plist" and look for: `URL Types` key. One of the sub-keys in there will open the application.

**Update:**

- Download the app on any iOS device.
- Plug it into the computer.
- Download Apple Configurator 2 from the Mac Appstore.

Next open apple configurator and right click on your iOS device and press "Add".. then find the app you want to download. Once you find it, double click it and it will tell you that the app is already installed. DO NOT click any of the options on the popup.

Open a terminal and type:

`cd ~/Library/Group Containers/K36BKF7T3D.group.com.apple.configurator/Library/Caches/Assets/TemporaryItems/MobileApps/`

Then type: `open .` to open the directory.. You should now see the .ipa file..

Comment: We have iOS 11 now: .ipa files aren't downloaded any more to iPhones (striping) and the big files appear not to be .zip files any more. Any idea how it is done now?

Comment: Thanks, nice process! I wrote a script to help with the extraction of the string: [get_url_scheme_for_ios_app.sh](https://gist.github.com/joeytwiddle/f7656ccc78d90c4e59e924897b0c3dae)

Comment: Is there an updated answer now that the current macOS doesn't use iTunes?

Comment: @daniel; Yes. There is a section in this answer that shows `Update:` and it says to use `Apple Configurator 2` from the Mac Appstore and to open a terminal and cd to the app and retrieve the info.

Comment: @Brandon Yeah. I saw that. I only see [Apple Configurator](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id1037126344?mt=12) on a Google search and in the App Store.

Comment: @Brandon Do you know how I can figure out what other "parameters" to use with the schemes? I found string values in the array belonging to the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key in Info.plist. There is a PUSH_BASE key with a string value of the format "http://mobile-platform-push.domain.org", with "domain" as the name of the organization. There are also a CFBundleURLName key and a CFBundleIdentifier key, having an identical reverse url value - "org.domain.xxx". I don't have anyone at that organization that I can ask. I am about to post a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @daniel; What app are you looking at? Sometimes to figure out the parameters passed to the URL, I either decompile the app or use Charles Proxy. If you can share what app it is, perhaps I can help out.

Comment: @Brandon I started using Charles Proxy. I haven't used it for very long, so I'm not sure what significant things it shows and I'm not sure what to look for. The app is Member Tools for iOS listed under The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints. I recently found a tech section at the Church's website and discovered that they take volunteers to develop their apps. I didn't think to look before. I'll be learning more about this from the tech section. I'm not what would be appropriate for me to do. I recall back when Microsoft kept enabling MSN Messenger to work with AOL's messaging app.

Comment: @daniel; The app makes a POST request to: `https://mobileauth.churchofjesuschrist.org/v1/mobile/login` with body: `{"password": "....", "username": "...."}`. Then it makes POST request to `https://ident.churchofjesuschrist.org/sso/oauth2/access_token?scope=openid%20profile&client_secret=9IA8oGJMHsfixNRHtLIcRgidJCKIPUkL&client_id=IIQm75tMcRzFEREV&grant_type=client_credentials` which responds with: `{ "access_token": "...", "scope": "openid profile", "id_token": "eyJ...", "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 1799}`. This service callback URL is `membertools://` with that info.

Comment: @daniel; This URL may be of some help to you when doing the OAUTH: `https://cdn.churchofjesuschrist.org/mobile/config/account/v1/wam2_prod.json` as it contains the authorization + token request URLs.
This one will only work once you successfully complete auth: `https://wam-membertools-api.churchofjesuschrist.org/api/` and make requests with the token. It will give you a list of APIs you can call. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oh! Wow. Thank you very much. Did you figure that out by using Charles alone? I had noticed that when I log into churchofjesuschrist.org that the address bar to the browser showed what was sent or received, but it didn't show long enough for me to copy it before something different showed in the address bar. I think it was because the communication process went to the next step or the next request or reply. I've worked with this sort of thing before, but I never got settled into the right tools and the right documentation and resources that I needed. I don't even remember what to call this.

Comment: @daniel; Yes. All of it is figured out with Charles. I enabled SSL proxying in Charles, and just grabbed all the requests and responses. Works for 99% of apps and websites (because most don't have SSL pinning). I also did reverse engineer the app a bit, to confirm that it doesn't contain a URL scheme handler, and that it's all handled by the OAuth framework being used :) For the `membertools://` scheme, I did what this answer does with Apple Configurator to get the IPA and checked the plist. But yes, Charles gave the most info and all the requests and responses.

Comment: @Brandon Ok. I had already downloaded Apple Configurator. One of the answers I ran into, maybe yours, said Apple Configurator 2, but when I only found Apple Configurator. Maybe that's the same thing and just doesn't say "2".

Comment: @Brandon This is the [app I am working on](https://apple.co/3EKcsMe). Or the next version of this app. I am able to get the Share Extension working so that Member Tools shares a list of people's names with my app. I am still waiting to hear from that organization. I'm hoping to be able to be able to get more from Member Tools than just names in a string value.