# Find url scheme of iOS app?

Tags: ios

I am developing some functionality in my application to allow a user to launch another app from my app.

It seems like the best way to do that is to leverage the URL scheme (if any) defined by the app I want to open.

The question I have is how do I know the URL schemes of another app coming from the store. I don't have access to the app's info.plist.

Is there any way to find third party apps URL schemes?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37951190/1226963

Comment: Not all apps have a custom scheme. You have to know the scheme and add it to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key in your Info.plist before you ship your app if you want to use `canOpenURL`.