# swift - App does not open from another app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurlconnection, func

I try to open Uber app from my app. It redirects me straight to the appstore, not to the app. I would like it to open Uber app directly not via appstore app. Here is my function:

```swift
func callUrl(){
    if let url = NSURL(string: "Uber://"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL)
    } else if let itunesUrl = NSURL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/uber/id368677368"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(itunesUrl as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(itunesUrl as URL)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `Uber` to your `LSApplicationQueriesStrings` in your info.plist?

Comment: Are you sure that is required to add it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `else` statement get called because maybe `"Uber://"` is a not valid key to open the app directly.

Maybe this will work for you

```swift
if let url = URL(string: "uber://"),
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {

    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
else {
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/uber/id368677368")!)
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key to `Info.plist` with `uber` value

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>uber</string>
</array>
```

[Uber Documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/ios#configuring-the-sdk)

Comment: Tried it but still the same issue

Comment: this means `canOpenURL()` returns false and it directs you to appstore, so could you please share more details? like the result of print `UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)` `false` etc.

Comment: Thats the log:  ```-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "uber://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme uber"
2020-04-07 16:07:14.632232+0200 Toasty Kiepscy[4558:1033901] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.```

Comment: @PawelZet please check my edited answer, I hope it will work

Comment: Cool, works now! Thank you :) I would know it in the future.

Comment: @emrcftci, Hi emrcfci , How to find the URL. I need to open swedbank private app. But cannot find the url. It always redirect to app store.

Comment: @Saravanan Have you found the solution?
i experienced the same thing

Comment: @emrcftci Is there any other way to get the key (uber) other than reading the documentation?
because the application I want to open has no documentation

Comment: maybe this SO question will help y'all -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318063/find-the-url-scheme-of-an-app-on-my-iphone

Comment: @Ali Hi, Are you using wkwebview? before entering swish payment app?

Comment: @Saravanan I don't use wkwebview

Comment: @emrcftci Thank you for your reference, really appreciate it